# Deploy new version of Apps Script using Google Apps Script java API

Tags: google-apps-script, deployment, google-api, google-apps-script-api

I am using the Google App Script java [API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/reference/rest/) to deploy the code. I am performing the following steps:

**1. Update the latest code**

```
Content content = new Content();
content.setFiles(files);
Content updatedContent = scriptService.projects().updateContent(scriptId, content).execute();
```

**2. Create a new version**

```
Version version = new Version();
version.setDescription("test create version");
Version createdVersion = scriptService.projects().versions().create(scriptId, version).execute();
```

**3. Deploy the latest version**

```
DeploymentConfig deploymentConfig = new DeploymentConfig();
deploymentConfig.setDescription("test deployment");
deploymentConfig.setVersionNumber(createdVersion.getVersionNumber());
deploymentConfig.setManifestFileName("appsscript");

Deployment deploymentCreated = scriptService.projects().deployments().create(scriptId, deploymentConfig).execute();
```

When I log into script.google.com I am able to view the latest version that I created. It shows the status as `deployed`. In the script editor, I am able to view the latest code as well. Now, when I invoke the apps script the requests are still handled by the older version. Could somebody let me know if there is something wrong with the way I am using the API?

Comment: Is this a Java or PHP command-line application?

Comment: This is a java based application

Comment: Add Java to the tags and add that it's Apps Script API using Java.  And maybe link to the Java quick start.  [https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/quickstart/java](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/quickstart/java)  The code is affecting Apps Script files, but none of the code is actually Apps Script code.  It's Java and API code.

Comment: The screen: "Publish API executable" - Does it show that the deployed version is the latest version?

Comment: Yes, the `Versions` drop-down shows the latest version. But, in the "Publish API executable" screen the newest version is not pre-selected in the drop-down.

Comment: This seems to be a known issue https://github.com/google/clasp/issues/63 Try creating a issue at https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new

Comment: Created an issue in Issue tracker - https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/119886997

Answer (score 0):

1. try to set deployment version (greater then old one).

   ```
   Version version = new Version();
   version.setDescription("test create version");
   version.setVersionNumber(3);
   Version createdVersion = scriptService.projects().versions().create(scriptId, version).execute();
   ```
2. delete the deployment when it's no longed needed

   ```
   service.projects().deployments()
       .delete(scriptId, deploymentCreated.getDeploymentId()).execute();
   ```